# Websocket get actual user online

Tags: node.js, websocket, count

I m working on Node js server.

In order to communicate with client i open websocket which should last for the whole user session. I need also to check if a user goes offiline. One way should to be to check the state of the web socket i.e. isReady or closed. I read there some situation which the onclose is not called. So what can be a trustable way to count the real current connected users?

Comment: which websocket library are you using at the server side?

Comment: require('ws').Server;

Comment: I used `ws` for two years and I can safely say its `wss.clients` count are accurate, all events are working properly. Just make sure you handle all the events fired by the lib and don't mess up the connection pool.